# Warning MT1108 after ios update

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

How do I fix:

`warning MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 6.1.3 (10B329) device. Please ensure you are using a compatible Xcode version and then connect this device to Xcode to install the development support files.`

I updated my `iPad` to new version of `iOS` and this started happening...I updated my xcode version to the latest stable version (`Xcode 5`, I believe)...I still have `xcode 4 on my computer how do I get this stop happening...

Comment: Have you tried creating a project in Xcode and run it on the device? And which Xamarin.iOS version do you have?

Comment: it says its using xamarin.ios 6.2.7.1 and xcode 4.5.2 when I go to about xamarin - but i upgraded to xcode 5 do i need to point to xamarin studio to the new xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need Xcode 4.6 - which was the version shipping support for the iOS 6.1 SDK. Xcode 4.5 shipped support for iOS6 while Xcode 5 **previews** (not stable) ships support for iOS7.

In general a later version will be ok, but sometimes the changes are too big (e.g. moving from `gcc` to `clang`) that this *might* not work. Also the NDA around iOS7 and Xcode5 means you're unlikely to get help here (or in other public forums).

So if you're developing for iOS 6.1 (the released, stable version of iOS) you should be using Xcode 4.6 (the stable tools/SDK) so you can deploy your applications to the appstore.

Comment: oh ok thanks...I will try this - I thought Xcode 5 was the latest stable release...