# warning MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 9.0 (13A344) device

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios9

I am having an issue with debugging my iOS application. When I try and run it on iOS9 it comes back with the following log:

> Connected to: iPhone 5 warning MT1003: Could not kill the
>   application 'com.<....>'. You may have to kill the
>   application manually.
>
> warning MT1108: Could not find developer tools
>   for this 9.0 (13A344) device. Please ensure you are using a compatible
>   Xcode version and then connect this device to Xcode to install the
>   development support files.
>
> error MT1007: Failed to launch the
>   application 'com.<....>' on the device
>   'iPhone 5': Look for earlier warnings returned: 0x454. You can still
>   launch the application manually by tapping on it.

I believe this is related to few other things online:

- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15886/getting-compile-time-error-mt1007
- [Warning MT1108 after ios update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494345/warning-mt1108-after-ios-update)
- [Xcode 7 with iOS 9 device Error: device unavailable (Could not find a developer disk image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542036/xcode-7-with-ios-9-device-error-device-unavailable-could-not-find-a-developer) ?

My guess to solving this would have been to simply download Xcode 7 ( I am running Xcode 6.4 at the moment). However I am slightly hesitant because [Xamarin's website](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/ios9/) suggests differently?

> To ensure your existing Xamarin.iOS apps run smoothly on iOS 9,
>   download the latest Xamarin.iOS release (8.10.3.2) from our Stable
>   channel (or if you have the previously released 8.10.1.74 that will
>   also work) (release info) then re-build and re-deploy your apps using
>   Xcode 6 on OS X Yosemite.
>
> This will allow your existing apps to run in iOS 9 previews, and be
>   ready for the public release of iOS 9.

Obviously, my app does install and normally on the iOS9 device. However I can't debug which makes development not ideal...
I have the latest Xamarin updates and I am running on OSX 10.10.4

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to just simply rebuild your app so it runs on iOS 9 (but build against iOS 8 SDK) then you can ignore the warning and tap the app to launch it and connect the debugger and continue from there (as it mentions).

If you're looking to use the new iOS 9 APIs in your application, then you'll need to get Xcode 7 installed.

Comment: Nice and simple. Thank you.